# How to get offline access to files in Google Drive using Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, cloud, google-drive

I'm using Google Drive through Nautilus [as described here](http://www.linuxtechi.com/access-google-drive-in-ubuntu-16-04/). However, there is no way to access to the files in offline mode like other third-party software. I wonder if, in Nautilus, Google Drive has some tricks to access the files while offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in your cron tab which once you are connected to the web will sync (rsync) your online files to a local folder.

This way you will have acess to your files oofline